# Firebase Android authentication error even with public rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am exploring Firebase Storage and have created a new folder named "data" on my app's firebase console, with a file inside named "info.json".

Since it's a new project and I don't have authentication setup, I copied the public security rules and applied them for the app:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

So far, I have only been using firebase-core for analytics, so I added firebase-storage. Firebase dependencies:

```
dependencies {
 api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
 api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
}
```

Here's my code, copied from Firebase samples:

```
val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
val storageRef = storage.reference
val pathReference = storageRef.child("data/info.json")
val ONE_MEGABYTE = (1024 * 1024).toLong()
val task = pathReference.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener {
    d { it.toString() }
}.addOnFailureListener {
    it.printStackTrace()
    d { it.toString() }
}
```

I am getting this error from last couple of hours:

> E/StorageUtil: error getting token
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: firebase-auth is
>   not linked, please fall back to unauthenticated mode.

Comment: Did you find any solution

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: any workaround?

Comment: Was a resolution found for this? I too am having the exact same issue (with Flutter).